# Ctrl + Alt + Arrow key doesn't switch workspaces

Tags: 12.10, unity, compiz, shortcut-keys, workspaces

My <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow key</kbd> fails to switch my workspace, but this is only true if

1. <kbd>NumLock</kbd> is on
2. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> followed by the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key
3. I'm using the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key
4. I'm logged in as me (as opposed to a guest)

Any help debugging this weird behavior would be greatly appreciated. It's a pretty frustrating little bug that gets in my way at least 20 times a day, and it's so strange that I would really just like to understand how it could be happening, although I wouldn't mind just fixing it with some kind of keybindings/unity/compiz reset. I just need some pointers on how to achieve this reset. Thanks!

Comment: I have almost the same problem in 13.04. It's working only in guest mode with Ctrl + Left Alt + Arrow keys (nothing to do with NumLock).

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again? Workspaces, that is. http://i.imgur.com/3MNKZ3F.png

Comment: I didn't try toggling it through that menu. I was thinking it's a keybinding problem, since workspaces works fine, it doesn't get triggered by a very specific key sequence.

Answer (score 24):

I've solved it by enabling **Desktop Wall** in [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/):

[image: Desktop Wall - CCSM]

Comment: I had Desktop Wall enabled. I tried toggling it to no effect.

Comment: @Noah For me this worked.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Comment: I had to disable the shortcuts in Window Management after installing CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Comment: It also works in 15.10

Comment: Worked for me in 16.04... somehow an update caused this to get disabled :S

Comment: Same here. CCSM fixed it on 16.04.  But how to fix this from the command line without CCSM?  I'd like to know what setting got changed without my doing anything.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem had to do with a conflict between the Desktop Wall plugin and the Grid plugin.  After I invoked Compiz Config Settings Manager (CCSM), and I unchecked and checked Desktop Wall, CCSM gave me the option of disabling the key bindings of the Grid plugin that conflicted with Desktop wall. To be safe, I disabled the Grid plugin.  My <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys are working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem running on a virtual machine and it turned out that VMWare Workstation was capturing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> to switch between active virtual machines.

In WMWare Workstation > Virtual Machine > Preferences > Hot Keys, I changed the hot key combination to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd> Key.

Answer (score 3):

I've you've come here (like me) for the title alone (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> key doesn't switch workspaces) then additionally to other answers here, try increasing the SIZE of your desktop:

`Compiz > General settings > "Desktop size" tab > if it's 1x1, increase it`

Credit to [Uchiha Madara's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26628/cant-switch-workspaces#comment371111_26671) in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem since today.
This bug?
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1212987

It seems that only (compiz Config Settings manager) CCSM is able to change workspaces from now on.
- general options
- Unity plugin

The Unity Tweak tool doesn't do anything since today. It shows the wrong amount and changing it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting anything in my home that sounded like a gnome or unity thing (.gconf, .gnome2, .kde). It obliterated all my unity settings, but it fixed the problem. I'm still curious to know how I could have done a more targeted fix.