# Ubuntu 14.04 workspace switch hotkeys

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, workspaces, shortcut-keys, workspace-switcher

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 and hotkeys for switching workspaces (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + arrow keys) are not working anymore.

I checked in System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts to make sure that they're assigned and they are, but why they are not working? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I turn on workspaces? (Why do I only have one workspace?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/260510/how-do-i-turn-on-workspaces-why-do-i-only-have-one-workspace)

Comment: nope, workspaces are already enabled, just hotkeys are not working.

Comment: If this was an upgrade the number of workspaces should have remained the same, I believe.

Answer (score 13):

I found the solution myself. It seems that I needed to enable Desktop Wall plugin in Compiz; just `apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`, run `ccsm` and search for "wall" to find the option.

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26628/cant-switch-workspaces/26671#26671) provides additional details which eventually helped me resolve this.

Comment: how do you do that exactly can you please share details?

Comment: same happened to me in ubuntu 16.04 and this solution solved it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This has broken for me a couple times now in Ubuntu; most recently after going from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS (in place upgrade).

- System Settings... (gear at top of screen)
- Appearance
- Behavior Tab
- Check box for Enable workspaces

Screen grab of configuration setting for workspaces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Reboot your system

And after than try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + arrow keys.
You will able to switch between workspaces.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work for me :( I'm able to switch between 1 and 2 while cannot go to 3 and 4 via 1 and 2. In other words I'm able to switch horizontal between 1 and 2, 3 and 4 while I'm not able to switch between 1 and 3, 2 and 4 :(