# 16.04 Switching between workspaces with the keyboard shortcuts do not work

Tags: 16.04, workspace-switcher

I rebooted today to apply the last security patch and now I can't switch between my workspaces. Usually, the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>CTLR</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>(**Arrow up/down/left/right**)</kbd> was working fine.

I checked system's settings and the feature is still active and shortcuts too.
Any idea why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Workplace switcher stopped working in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819585/workplace-switcher-stopped-working-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: you are welcome! :)