# Workspaces and maximizing not working

Tags: 16.04, workspaces, window, workspace-switcher, maximized

I'm using ubuntu 16.04lts, and today I've noticed that the shortcut to switch in between workspaces and to move windows between workspaces stopped working. Also, when I grab a window and move it to the upper border of the monitor it doesn't maximize. Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you rebooted the computer to see if that solves the problem? Otherwise you can install `compizconfig-settings-manager` to check/reset these settings. Cheers, Al

Comment: I've rebooted the computes a few times but it didn't solve it. I'll try with compiz. Thanks!

Comment: Try compizconfig. Also, try logging into the `Guest` login, and see if it all works there (this would eliminate something in your own home directory causing the problem). Cheers, Al

Comment: I did what you said, and it works fine. So it's something from my own directory. Thanks.

Comment: Try renaming **/home/your_username/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig** folder from compizconfig to compizconfig.HOLD, logout, login, and see if it all works now. If it does, let me know and I'll put more detail in an answer. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only thing that doesn't work is the maximize when I drag a window to the upper border. The workspaces work just fine.

Comment: Progress! Open a Nautilus window, and type **control-h** to show hidden files. Now rename the .config folder to .config.HOLD, logout, login, and see if all the things work now. If nothing changes, move the new .config folder out to the desktop (to be trashed later), and rename .config.HOLD back to .config, logout, login. If it DOES fix the problem, then something in the .config folder is causing the problem. Don't delete the original .config folder, or all of its contents, as all of your configuration data is in that folder. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workspace switching**: I could fix it by

1. Installing Compizconfig Settings Manager (from Software Center)
2. open Compizconfig Settings Manager
3. Click on Desktop
4. Enable the tick box for "Desktop Wall"

This solution was derived from [Can't switch workspaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26628/cant-switch-workspaces) (however, the explanation there wasn't very clear to me :-) )

Hope this helps.

**Window behaviour on borders**:

1. open Compizconfig Settings Manager
2. Click on Window Management
3. Enable the tick box for "Grid"
4. Several issues with key binding conflicts may appear (I chose to resolve conflicts and then said don't assign to all the proposed key bindings..this work, but it's up to you to decide differently)

Hope this helps as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could not try what you said. I had a problem with my previous computer, so they gave me a new one at work. Now everything works perfect!