# Workspaces don't switch anymore - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, workspaces, shortcuts, workspace-switcher

My workspaces don't switch anymore, neither if I use shortcuts, nor if I want to access a window from a workspace to another.. 
I customed my keyboard shortcuts "Switch to workspace above/below" in Settings, but that changed nothing.

Can somebody help me please ? Thanks :)

Comment: This helped me
https://askubuntu.com/questions/833439/workspaces-and-maximizing-not-working